# Transforming inertia tensor from corner of a beam to the centre

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia

So I have a beam with mass M and sides a (x-direction) ,b (y-direction) and c (z-direction). I have figured out that the inertia tensor in the corner is 
$$I = M\begin{bmatrix} \frac{b^2 + c^2}{3} & -\frac{ab}{4} & -\frac{ac}{4}\\ -\frac{ab}{4} & \frac{a^2+c^2}{3} & -\frac{bc}{4} \\ -\frac{ac}{4} & -\frac{bc}{4} & \frac{a^2+b^2}{3}\end{bmatrix}$$
and in the middle a nice diagonal matrix 
$$I = \frac{M}{12}\begin{bmatrix} b^2+c^2 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & a^2 + c^2 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & a^2 + b^2 \end{bmatrix}$$
and I know the vector you should use to transform from the corner to the middle is
$$ R = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{a}{2} \\ \frac{b}{2} \\ \frac{c}{2} \end{bmatrix}$$
but I don't really get how I would for example transform the $I_{zz}$ component of the corner to the middle with the transform formula $I_a = I_b + MR^2$

Comment: Doing it component by component is arduous and error-prone. Use linear algebra to help you keep track of sign conventions and all the necessary combinations of coordinates. See my answer below for the general rule on how to handle these kind of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3D form of the parallel axis theorem is defined as follows.

[image: mmoi]

$$ \mathbf{I}_A = \mathbf{I}_C + m \left( -[\boldsymbol{c} \times][\boldsymbol{c} \times] \right) $$

where $[\boldsymbol{c}\times] = \pmatrix{0 & -z & y\\z & 0 & -x\\-y & x & 0}$ is the 3×3 cross product operator matrix. Combined the above expression is

$$ \mathbf{I}_A = \mathbf{I}_C + m \begin{vmatrix} y^2+z^2 & -x y & -x z \\ -x y & x^2 + z^2 & -y z \\ -x z & -y z & x^2+y^2 \end{vmatrix} $$

<sub>Do you see the pattern in the above? The diagonal elements are the sum of squares of the vector components excluding the row of the diagonal (1st row has 2nd and 3rd components, etc.) and the non diagonals contains the negative product of the vector components of the row and column (the 2nd row, 3rd column contains $-y z$).</sub>

Using the above you can solve for $\mathbf{I}_C$ at the center given the mass moment of inertia tensor at the corner $\mathbf{I}_A$ and the position vector of the center $\boldsymbol{c} = \pmatrix{ a/2 \\ b/2 \\ c/2 }$.

Comment: This seems about right and thank you, but I still don't quite understand where the 3x3 cross product operator matrix came from tho

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Conversion_to_matrix_multiplication) on how it is derived. Essentially $$ \vec{a} \times \vec{b} = [\vec{a}\times] \vec{b} = \pmatrix{0 & -a_z & a_y \\ a_z & 0 & -a_x \\ -a_y & a_x & 0} \pmatrix{b_x \\ b_y \\ b_z} $$

Comment: The derivation of the MMOI formula comes from finding the angular momentum of a particle as it rotates about the origin with $\boldsymbol{\omega}$. Consider the following $$\boldsymbol{L}=\boldsymbol{c}\times m \boldsymbol{v}=\boldsymbol{c}\times m \left( \boldsymbol{\omega}\times\boldsymbol{c}\right)= -\boldsymbol{c}\times m \left(\boldsymbol{c}\times\boldsymbol{\omega}\right)=m \left(- [\boldsymbol{c}\times][\boldsymbol{c}\times]\right)\boldsymbol{\omega}$$

Comment: Now I get it! Thanks again!